# How to add custom data to ChoicePrompt with ListStyle.heroCard

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, botframework, chatbot

I have a `ChoicePrompt` with style `ListStyle.heroCard` as follow:

```
import {ChoicePrompt, ListStyle} from 'botbuilder-dialogs';
import {PromptValidator} from 'botbuilder-dialogs/src/prompts/prompt';
import {FoundChoice} from 'botbuilder-dialogs/src/choices/findChoices';

export class HeroCardChoicePrompt extends ChoicePrompt{
    constructor(dialogId: string, validator?: PromptValidator<FoundChoice>, defaultLocale?: string){
        super(dialogId, validator, defaultLocale)
        this.style = ListStyle.heroCard
    }
}
```

Then I added this choice object:

```
choices.push({
    action: {

        text: 'Lolipop',
        displayText: 'Lolipop',
        channelData: 'Lolipop',

        type: 'postBack',
        title:  'Lolipop',
        value:  'Lolipop',

    },
    value: 'Can you please help me to manage...',
    synonyms: []
},)
```

How do I get the data `'Lolipop'` in my code when the user clicks on the choice?

When I check the JSON object received by the client in the bot emulator, I do not see the data `'Lolipop'` at all.

[image: m]

Comment: I presume you posted this as well: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/1286

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ListStyle.heroCard` makes the prompt use `ChoiceFactory.heroCard` to generate the card. You can see in the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/4.5/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/choices/choiceFactory.ts#L138-L147) that `ChoiceFactory.heroCard` doesn't use the actions in the choices and instead just creates `imBack` actions:

> ```
> const buttons: CardAction[] = choices.map(choice => ({
>     title: choice.value,
>     type: ActionTypes.ImBack,
>     value: choice.value
> } as CardAction));
> ```

If you want to supply custom actions in your prompt then you'll need to create your own hero card and supply it as the `prompt` field of your prompt options and use `ListStyle.none`. It's unclear why you'd want to do that because the actions generated by `ChoiceFactory` will match the available choices in the choice prompt so there's no need for the activity to have a hidden value.

Comment: The button should display : 'Can you please help me to manage...' but return 'Lolipop'

Comment: @TSR - Okay, I just explained that you can accomplish that by creating your own hero card. But why do you want it to do that? Aren't you using a choice prompt?